# Css Color Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the color of some jQuery UI sortable using CSS:
Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fwcLd8mg/2/

When I set the .default background all the boxes turn to that color.
But when I specify background in each list, the background of the list changes, not the boxes.

How do i specify colors for the boxes?

**CSS:**

```
#sortable-5 {
background: #ff0000;
}
#sortable-6 {
background: #00b8ff;
}
#sortable-7{
background: #000000;
}
#sortable-5, #sortable-6,#sortable-7 { 
list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;
width: 20%;float:left
}
#sortable-5 li, #sortable-6 li,#sortable-7 li { 
margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; 
padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 17px; height: 50px;
}
.default {
background: #b2f5fb;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fwcLd8mg/3/)?

Comment: @chriz Yes Thank You! I got three working examples!

Comment: Nice! Make sure you accept one of the other answers if that has worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background color of the boxes (.default) in each list you need to make it like this

```
#sortable-5 .default{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/fwcLd8mg/6/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the colours to the `LI` elements.  Since you've added a `default` class to them, you can use that:

```
#sortable-5>.default {
    background: #ff0000;
}
#sortable-6>.default {
    background: #00b8ff;
}
#sortable-7>.default{
    background: #000000;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxyfb2dj/1/)